# Passing parameters to a build-in Quick Create form in Dynamics 365 (Account to Contact)

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

[This](http://dotnetdust.blogspot.co.uk/) blog entry discusses a way to pass custom parameters to a Quick Create form (from a parent form). I'm trying to do the same when a Quick Create form is opened on the Contacts sub-grid in an Account parent form using the + button as shown below (this is a build-in relationship in the Sales business App):

[image: Quick Create Contact]

The blog entry then goes on to discuss how to update the Xrm.Utility.openQuickCreate 'call site' (in the 'The Task' section). Is there anywhere I can find the 'call site' for the build-in + button on the Contact subgrid for the Account entity so that I can pass parameters to the Quick Create: Contact form?

Comment: Leave a comment in blog, so Daryl can respond to you about call site quickly..

Comment: My guess is it should be a typo :)

Comment: Did you setup the parameter tab in both default form & quick create form - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg334436.aspx#Define%20allowed%20query%20string%20parameters?

Comment: @ArunVinoth Thanks! Yes, I will leave a comment on Daryl's blog later today and link back here. I'm not sure I understand how parameters work entirely in this context; when I set up a parameter, do I not need to update client script to pass it to the Quick Create Form? I seems Daryl has written some custom code to open the form, but how do I do that when it is a build-in relationship using a subgrid? (between Account and Contact).

Comment: I personally never tried this. But referring this blog https://neilparkhurst.com/2015/10/24/open-quick-create-or-entity-forms-from-javascript/ you may need a custom + button in subgrid ribbon after hiding OOB +

Comment: You can either create a custom + button or you can change the command that the + button calls. To do this you will either need to change the RibbonDiff yourself or use the Ribbon workbench

Comment: @StefanWilliam-Worrall and Arun, thank you both. I'll look into trying both RibbonDiff and the Ribbon workbench (neither of which I have used before) and give an update. I associated 'ribbon' with the top ribbon, I didn't know a subgrid can have a 'ribbon' as well, so I never thought of using the workbench.